# Azure - How to delete database from secondary fail over group if it doesn't exist in the primary

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm having a problem with azure in trying to remove a database that exists in a secondary fail over group but doesn't exist in the primary. I've not idea how it got into this state....

If I try to add to the primary....

```
$failoverGroup = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "SASepa" -ServerName "sasepa" -DatabaseName "SEPA-e0e9c319-6237-4c2a-9204-cf9bd53f4a83Test" | Add-AzSqlDatabaseToFailoverGroup -ResourceGroupName "SASepa" -ServerName "sasepa" -FailoverGroupName "sa-sepa-test-fog" -Debug
```

I get the following error...

```
{
  "error": {
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "45138",
        "message": "The destination database name 'SEPA-e0e9c319-6237-4c2a-9204-cf9bd53f4a83Test' already exists on the
 server 'sasepa-geo'."
      }
    ],
    "code": "FailoverGroupUnableToPerformGroupOperationOnDatabases",
    "message": "The operation cannot be performed due to multiple errors."
  }
}
```

If I try to delete from the secondary based on the above error....

```
$failoverGroup = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "SASepa" -ServerName "sasepa-geo" -DatabaseName "SEPA-e0e9c319-6237-4c2a-9204-cf9bd53f4a83Test" | Remove-AzSqlDatabaseFromFailoverGroup -ResourceGroupName "SASepa" -ServerName "sasepa-geo" -FailoverGroupName "sa-sepa-test-fog" -Debug
```

I get the following error...

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "FailoverGroupUpdateOrDeleteRequestOnSecondary",
    "message": "Modifications to the failover group are not allowed on a secondary server. Execute the request on the
primary server."
  }
}
```

If I try to modify the primary group by removing the database with the following command...

```
$failoverGroup = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "SASepa" -ServerName "sasepa" -DatabaseName "SEPA-e0e9c319-6237-4c2a-9204-cf9bd53f4a83Test" | Remove-AzSqlDatabaseFromFailoverGroup -ResourceGroupName "SASepa" -ServerName "sasepa" -FailoverGroupName "sa-sepa-test-fog" -Debug
```

I get the following error...

```
WARNING: Database to be removed with id
/subscriptions/4c193689-f235-4d0d-9aa9-006459abc199/resourceGroups/SASepa/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sasepa/databa
ses/SEPA-e0e9c319-6237-4c2a-9204-cf9bd53f4a83Test in Failover Group with name: 'sa-sepa-test-fog'  in server 'sasepa
does not exist'.
```

So I'm stuck in a loop

- I can't add to the primary as it says it already exists on the secondary
- I can't remove from the secondary as it says I need to perform modifications on the primary
- I can't remove from the primary as it doesn't exist

How can I resolve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you remove it on Portal?

Comment: I create a failover group and add two databases(Mydatabase and DB1) to in it. I tried delete DB1 in primary server On Portal. Then database in the secondary fail will auto be deleted later.  So I'm a little confused that why your database that exists in a secondary fail over group but doesn't exist in the primary. You could refresh the failover group and check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a failover group and add two databases(Mydatabase and DB1) to in it. I tried delete DB1 in primary server On Portal. **Then database in the secondary fail will auto be deleted later**.

For example, when delete a database in primary server, see the warning:

[image]

Then I run the Powershell command remove the DB1 and get the same error with you.

[image]

[image]

I just wait a moment and refresh the failover group, the DB1 not exist now.

So I'm a little confused that why you say that the database exists in a secondary fail over group but doesn't exist in the primary. I think the most possible reason is caused by the cache.

You could refresh the failover group and check again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did in fact appear to be a caching issue. After coming back to it after a day, I was able to re-add the database to the primary failover group and it was automatically 
replicated into the secondary, without complaining about already existing.